# error establishing connection between js client and python server in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome, websocket

I am trying to connect between js client and python server in chrome extension platform, but getting error in the connection establishment.
It is important to note that the code worked in cmd test, but when I tried to make the connection in the chrome extension, it gets an error. So if someone had already deal with something similar, please check the code and help me to figure what is wrong with it.

I used `serversocket` module.
Here is the server:

```
clients = []
class MyTCPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
 def handle(self):
  if self not in clients:
   clients.append(self)
  self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
  if self.data == "":
   clients.remove(self)
  print(self.data)
  arr=self.data.split('~')
  result=algo(arr)
  self.request.send(result)

if _name_ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = '127.0.0.1', 6169
    server = socketserver.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)
    print("hi")
    # interrupt the program with Ctrl-C
    server.serve_forever()
```

The alerts and some of the `if` are for checking

and the client:

```
 var st="password11"+"~"+"www.google.com"+"~"+"1656226256";
   //"wss://"+HOST+":"+PORT+"/"
   if ('WebSocket' in window){
    alert("websocket");
       var socket = new WebSocket("wss://127.0.0.1:6169/", ['soap', 'xmpp']);
    socket.onopen = function (evt) {
     alert("connection opened");
     socket.send(st);
    };
    socket.onmessage = function (evt) {
     alert("Message from remote server : "+evt.data);
     socket.close();
    };
    socket.onerror = function (evt) {
     alert(evt.data);
    };
    socket.onclose = function (evt) {
     alert("connection closed");
    };
   }
    else {
      alert("web socket is not supported")
   }
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: @Barmar 
 WebSocket connection to 'wss://127.0.0.1:6169/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED